# Is it viable to have a database table for each user?

Tags: database, web-applications

Is it common or viable for large web applications to have a separate database table for each user?  If not, how do most go about storing large sets of data for each individual user(most notably large arrays(in the hundreds of thousands or millions)) when there is usually a size limitation on rows?

Comment: Surely it is not common to have a table for each user and nobody will suggest you to do.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa how would you store large arrays of integers in a row in a mySQL table where there is a limit of 65kB?

Comment: The questions are: Can you refactor your code to better partition and store the data? Is Mysql a constraint or a choice? If it is a choice can you change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from what read (both in the comments and elsewhere on SO) I've concluded that it is suggested not to design a database this way.  Thanks for your comments